# Hibernate HQL russian letters

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

When i try to use russian letters in hql i t returns nothing

```
ArrayList<Route> result=(ArrayList<Route>)session.createQuery("select distinct r" +
            " from StationAssignment sa " +
            " join sa.route r" +
            " join sa.station s" +
            " where lower( s.title)='москва' or lower( s.title)='саратов'" +
            " group by r" +
            " having count(r)=2").list();
```

log:

> Hibernate: select distinct route1_.id as id1_3_, route1_.Title as
>   Title2_3_ from StationAssignment stationass0_ inner join Route route1_
>   on stationass0_.route_id=route1_.id inner join Station station2_ on
>   stationass0_.Station_id=station2_.id where
>   lower(station2_.Title)='РјРѕСЃРєРІР°' or
>   lower(station2_.Title)='СЃР°СЂР°С‚РѕРІ' group by route1_.id having
>   count(route1_.id)=2

hibernate cfg

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" >jdbc:postgresql://vm12467.hv8.ru/dbname</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

My encoding in IDEA utf-8
if i try to do this

```
ArrayList<Route> result=(ArrayList<Route>)session.createQuery("select distinct r" +
            " from StationAssignment sa " +
            " join sa.route r" +
            " join sa.station s" +
            " where lower( s.title)=:name1 or lower( s.title)=:name2" +
            " group by r" +
            " having count(r)=2").
            setParameter("name1",startStationName.toLowerCase()).
            setParameter("name2",endStationName.toLowerCase()).list();
```

i have something

Comment: what 'show server_encoding;' says in pgsql?

Comment: There also can be a problem with client encoding. Take a look at this: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1006879